# Стили как у button

Tags: html, css, css3

Здравствуйте!
Ситуация следующая:

Есть div. Нужно, чтоб он вёл себя с контентом внутри как кнопка. То есть, чтоб текст и блоки внутри выравнивались по центру (по вертикали и горизонтали) и чтоб при изменении размеров border не менялись внутренние и внешние размеры блока.

Вопрос может и глупый, но я в css ещё относительно новичёк, так что прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.div_btn{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
  background: tomato;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.div_btn a{
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_btn">
  <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: если чего-то здесь не хватает, пишите

Comment: И как это я, интересно, забыл про justify...

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

```css
.button {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family: "Helvetica", "Roboto";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="button">Моя кнопочка</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn {
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 120px;
    text-align: center; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none; 
    background: #FFEB3B;
    outline: none !important;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Кнопка</div>
<br/>
<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
```